# Android ImageView change maxHeight property through code

Tags: android, imageview

I have a **scrollable view** in which I'm inserting various views programatically. **Some views are text fields, some are images.**

Most of the images that I insert are horizontal images but **some of the images are vertical.** For vertical images I want to modify my ImageView's maxHeight property programatically. So I've put an **approximate check if(height > (width * 1.3) )**

This is my Imageview xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@null"
android:maxHeight="200dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

And this is my code:

```
if (h > (1.3 * w)) {
    imageView.setMaxHeight(500);
}
```

But this doesn't work. Can anybody tell me why & what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since your value 500 is a pixel value. So, I think you need to convert 500 to corresponded dp value. Try to use this:

```
    private int dpToPx(int dp, Activity activity) {
        Resources r = activity.getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }
```

and change your code to this:

```
if (h > (1.3 * w)) {
    imageView.setMaxHeight(dpToPx(500, this));
}
```

Comment: Tried. Didn't work.I think something more needs to be done for setMaxHeight() to work programatically. Maybe it doesn't work after the view is rendered